# How to convert UNIX Timestamps captured by Debezium into normal timestamps in Kafka

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm working with Debezium + Kafka to perform CDC on a MySQL Database.  Everything is working but i'm running into an issue with the `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` column formats in MySQL mapping over to Kafka.

For any `TIMESTAMP` columns they get stored in this format `"2023-06-22T19:29:26Z"` in Kafka, which is perfect for my use case and works fine.  However, any `DATETIME` columns are getting stored as UNIX timestamps `1687462166000`, which does not work for my use case.

I'll have to spend a significant amount of time re-engineering things if these columns are stored as UNIX timestamps across like 50+ different tables in my project, so I'm looking for an easy way to get those `DATETIME` values stored in Kafka the same as the `TIMESTAMP` ones are.  I've been looking at SMTs but haven't found a great solution yet.  I'm hoping I can fix this by adding a few parameters to the Debezium Config & call it a day.  Below is some more info to understand what's going on.

Debezium Config

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  http://localhost:8083/connectors/mysql-debezium-test/config \
  -d '{
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "mysql",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.password": "dbz",
        "database.server.id": "44",
        "database.server.name": "asgard2",
        "table.whitelist": "demo.movies,demo.second_movies",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker:29092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.demo" ,
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
        "time.precision.mode": "adaptive",
        "transforms": "unwrap,dropTopicPrefix",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"asgard2.demo.(.*)",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"mysql2.$1",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "log.retention.hours": "120",
        "poll.interval.ms": "30000"
    }'
```

MySQL Table + Column Types Example

```
CREATE TABLE `movies`
(
    `movie_id`             int(11)       NOT NULL,
    `title`                varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `release_year`         int(11)       NOT NULL,
    `country`              varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `genres`               varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `actors`               varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    `directors`            varchar(512)  NOT NULL,
    `composers`            varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `screenwriters`        varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `cinematographer`      varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `production_companies` varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    `created_at`           TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `created_at_datetime`  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
);
```

Message as stored in Kafka

```
{
    "movie_id": 2,
    "title": "10,000 B.C. try 2",
    "release_year": 2008,
    "country": "United States",
    "genres": "Adventure",
    "actors": "Steven Strait|Camilla Belle|Cliff Curtis|Omar Sharif|Tim Barlow|Marco Khan|Reece Ritchie|Mo Zinal",
    "directors": "Roland Emmerich",
    "composers": "Harald Kloser|Thomas Wanker",
    "screenwriters": "Roland Emmerich|Harald Kloser|John Orloff|Matthew Sand|Robert Rodat",
    "cinematographer": "Ueli Steiger",
    "production_companies": "Warner Bros. Pictures|Legendary Pictures|Centropolis",
    "created_at": "2023-06-22T19:29:26Z",
    "created_at_datetime": 1687462166000,
    "__deleted": "false"
}
```

Raw data in MySQL

[image]

Anybody have any ideas on a quick fix that doesn't involve changing the actual column types in MySQL, or having to perform transformations in the application that consumes these Kafka messages?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Ahh so somewhere its converting from current timestamp into unixtimestamp.  Well .. one quick fix would be to convert it back before inserting it.  And as a note in 2038 Timestamp AND Unixtimestamp runs out of numbers and all apps that use them will break. But how to convert the time for you is found here --> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: note - you asked for the easiest thing to do, and since you are already generating a unixtime stamp, why not convert it before it inserts, and your problem is solved, no altering 50 other tables to support unixtimestamp, at least for a couple decades still.

Comment: i'm down to try any potential solution, but what did you have in mind?  these timestamps are generated in mysql with a default set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and then they show up in kafka as unix timestamps.  is there somewhere in between that i can convert them to something other than unix timestamps?

my application gets the kafka messaged dumped directly to it, i cant apply any transformations there i just get the values as-is.

Comment: Oh I have it backwards .. I thought it was the other way around .. I know in MySQL you can do like default expressions, so i wonder if something like that could handle the translation of the dates.  Man I wish I had more info for you, good luck!

Comment: There's a TimestampConverter transform for this. Have you tried using it? Otherwise, there's no reason I see to have two columns with the same timestamp in different formats

Comment: 1687462166000/1000 is a UNIXTIME.  The other needs some editing to get into a syntax compatible with DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.  Caution:  MySQL does not store TZ with either, however, TIMESTAMP uses the Locale to determine the conversion.

Comment: my tables were just an example.  my project has 40+ tables with a mix of datetime + timestamp mysql columns.  i've started using the `TimestampConverter` which seems to work to convert the UNIX timestamp to a timestamp value, but it will not let me include T and Z in the format `"transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",`.  I get an `Illegal pattern character 'T' for configuration TimestampConverter` error - is there any way to include these T and Z string values in the format?  i've tried using single quotes as well but get the same error.

Comment: update: seems like there are 2 options: this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX` which has an output value of `2023-06-25 17:45:11Z`, and this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ` which has an output value of `2023-06-25 17:45:11+0000`.  ideally i'd like to include the `T` to match the example in my post, but one of these should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KafkaConnect does neither  support `DateTime` type nor `Timestamp` type. that is why `Debezium` converts these data types to `Long` type and you need to use a Converter to fix it or switch to the `debezium-jdbc-connect`

Comment: If this is correct it explains the automatic conversion.  Just curious but is this Long type conversion UNIXTIMESTAMP ? or just looks like it ?

Comment: it's LongType conversion of unix timestamp and even you could set precision of it in MySQL connector using `time.precision.mode`